# How to get particular one database table data in custom php file magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

We have 'outofstocksubscription_info' table in database.
We want to it's all data in one custom php file.
How to get it in custom file ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    /**
     * Retrieve the read connection
     */
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('outofstocksubscription_info');

    /**
     * Execute the query and store the results in $results
     */
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

    /**
     * Print out the results
     */
     var_dump($results);
```

[reference](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/)

Comment: Thanks; its working. But in this table multiple columns and we want only 2 column value. I am not more familiar with coding.

Comment: replace 'select  * from'  with 'select column1name,column2name from'

Comment: in select query instead * you can use column name like: name, surname

Comment: @JimitBhavsar thanks it's working.

Comment: @JimitBhavsar this array has multi product SKU; and some are repeat in it. How to count it.